# ReactJS callback useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, getstream-io

While by following the [documentation](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/react/channel_delete/?language=javascript#hiding-a-channel) of GetStreamIO service I am trying to hide the channel message when a user connects to the channel, so that the previous message history will not be shown to a user.

```js
const App = () => {

  const [chatClient, setChatClient] = useState(null);
  const [channel, setChannel] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initChat = async () => {
      const client = StreamChat.getInstance(env.API_KEY);

      const _channel = await client.channel('livestream', env.ROOM_NAME);
      setChatClient(client);
      setChannel(_channel)
    };
    initChat();
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const hideChat = async () => {
      if(channel !== null) {
        console.log(channel);
        await channel.hide();
      }
    }
    hideChat(); 
  }, [channel])

  return (
      <Chat client={chatClient}>
        <Channel channel={channel}>
          <Window>
            <VirtualizedMessageList />
          </Window>
        </Channel>
      </Chat>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I am going to hide the messages through `channel.hide()` method after the state value of `channel` is updated, but this line throws an error of `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of null`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `setChatClient` function is async. It is posible that when `channel.hide()` runs, the channel value is null. I recommend you to hide the channel when it's value has changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(channel) channel.hide();
}, [channel]);
```

Comment: Not worked !!! I have replaced this snippet with that `await channel.hide()` method but now it is throwing an error of connection `Error: You can't use a channel after client.disconnect() was called`